# Отправка данных в форму

Tags: php

Имеем форму отправки данных в файл

```html
<input name="name" >
<textarea name="info"></textarea>
<button name="read">отправить</button>
```

И его обработчик:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['read']))
{    
    $info = $_POST['info'];  
    $f = fopen('send.txt','a+');  
    fputs($f,$info);       
    fclose($f);            
?>
```

так работает но как передать в $info второй параметр name ?

и как поступить если потребуется внести ещё `$_POST` параметры ?

Comment: `$_POST['name']` разве не работает?

Comment: @KostaB. работает но если указать два или больше то ошибка

Comment: `$info = ($_POST['info']); ($_POST['name']);` вот так отравляется name а info нет

Comment: `$info .= $_POST['name']` добваит к `$info`

Comment: @KostaB.  я не понял ..

Comment: я наверно так скопировал - в документё есть - только имя дубрируется и после обновления страницы это же сообщение приходит опять и третье все сообщения в строку ...не помогает \n и EOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.=` - конкатенация [Подробнее тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)

```
$info = $_POST['info'];



$info .= $_POST['name']; // Добавит к содержимому $info содержимое $_POST['name'];
```

---

**UPD**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['read']))
{    
    $info = $_POST['info'];  
    $info .=  " " . $_POST['name']; // Добавлен пробел между $info и $_POST['name']
    $f = fopen('send.txt','a+');  
    fputs($f,$info);       
    fclose($f);            
}
```

Comment: где дублируется name? (Вы можете отметить как принятый ответ, если это вам помгло)

Comment: Посмотрите другие места, где вы работаете с полями `input`.

Comment: Кроме того, что у вас пропущенна закрывающая скобка `if`, все работает без повторений.